# Google maps points to the correct location but does not show the location name

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I create a Google map for my site using the API.  It points to the correct location but the problem is it does not show the location name.

See: http://myrtlebeachsweeps.com/ticket/angelos-steak-and-pasta . Zoom-in.  Notice that the map shows the name of *Cancun Lagoon Golf* but it does not show the name of *Angelo's*.

[This direct Google maps link](http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=2011,South,Kings,Highway,+Myrtle+Beach,sc,usa+&sll=37.0625,-95.677068&sspn=32.059939,86.572266&ie=UTF8&hq=&hnear=2011+S+Kings+Hwy,+Myrtle+Beach,+Horry,+South+Carolina+29577&ll=33.671354,-78.908685&spn=0.001027,0.002642&z=19) shows the correct location and the name.   Both locations are the same but it does not show the location name in my site.

Please help.

### Update:

(From the OP)
[Link to the main JavaScript used](http://myrtlebeachsweeps.com/wp-content/themes/tttt/gsmapsearch.js?mode=new).

Map activating code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function LoadMapSearchControl() 
    {
        var options = { //zoomControl : GSmapSearchControl.ZOOM_CONTROL_ENABLE_ALL, // url : "http://www.google.com/corporate/index.html", idleMapZoom : 16, //activeMapZoom : GSmapSearchControl.ACTIVE_MAP_ZOOM }
        new GSmapSearchControl( document.getElementById("mapsearch"), "<? echo"$cmpyaddress"?>", options ); 
    }
    GSearch.setOnLoadCallback(LoadMapSearchControl); 
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean it shows the name in Google maps?  Provide a link that Google-maps page, or provide a picture of the correct behavior.

Comment: thanks Brock Adams
i mean that it show correct location with location name while zooming in google maps but not in my site please help me 
link is 
http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=2011,South,Kings,Highway,+Myrtle+Beach,sc,usa+&sll=37.0625,-95.677068&sspn=32.059939,86.572266&ie=UTF8&hq=&hnear=2011+S+Kings+Hwy,+Myrtle+Beach,+Horry,+South+Carolina+29577&ll=33.671354,-78.908685&spn=0.001027,0.002642&z=19

Comment: Please provide some code. You don't seem to be specifying a location name in your code - Google Maps won't determine it on its own.

Comment: @Pekka:  He has given enough.  (Although including code would certainly be better.)  This appears to be a bug in Google Maps.  For example, search in the general area like: http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=Cancun+Lagoon+Golf,+Myrtle+Beach,+SC&sll=37.0625,-95.677068&sspn=48.374125,66.533203&ie=UTF8&hq=Cancun+Lagoon+Golf,&hnear=Myrtle+Beach,+Horry,+South+Carolina&ll=33.671068,-78.909345&spn=0.00625,0.008122&z=17 .  Notice that the original location is in no way specified.  But the Angelo's Name does appear.

Comment: @Brock true, but shahul is talking about a custom map. The marker is missing the location's name in the source code, and it won't come up automatically. When you specify a marker in your own map, you need to give it a name. Or am I overlooking something?

Comment: @Pekka: Maybe that's it.  He specified a marker with no name and it overrode the map's default behavior?   (Just guessing).   @shahul, please supply the code you are using to invoke that map.

Comment: thanks
yes i am specified a marker with out name because google map doesn't showing that location 
is that any way to include the location name with the marker?
the entire code will get from this link 
http://myrtlebeachsweeps.com/wp-content/themes/tttt/gsmapsearch.js?mode=new

please forgive me if there is any fault 
because i am a beginner

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    function LoadMapSearchControl() {
      var options = {
            //zoomControl : GSmapSearchControl.ZOOM_CONTROL_ENABLE_ALL,

            
           // url : "http://www.google.com/corporate/index.html",

           idleMapZoom : 16,

            //activeMapZoom : GSmapSearchControl.ACTIVE_MAP_ZOOM

            }



      new GSmapSearchControl(

            document.getElementById("mapsearch"),

            "<? echo"$cmpyaddress"?>",

            options

            );



    }

   

    GSearch.setOnLoadCallback(LoadMapSearchControl);

  </script>

Comment: the above one is the calling script 
and the link is the js used for the map

Comment: @shahul: Don't paste or link to code in comments.  Edit your question with the updated info.

Answer (score 1):

The Maps API and Google Maps use different tile sets.

See http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/yourfirstmap.html section 3.5